# Display div only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, message

So I want to do look a like stackoverflow with the message at the top.

Now I have all configured and such, but I got one problem.. The message only displays 1st time, second time it doesn't appear.

I know why, something about every id must be unique or something in a div.. And then I've used `rand(1, 300);` (php) and it still won't work.

Here's my codes:

```
function checkSession(){
    $.ajax({url: "session.php", success: function(data){
         if( data == 1){
            var postFilen = 'msg.php';
            $.post(postFilen, function(data){
            $(".msg").html(data).find(".message2").fadeIn("slow")
            setTimeout(function(checkSession) {
    $('.msg').fadeOut('slow');
}, 10000);
            });  
         }else{ 
             $('.message2').hide();
         }
    }});
// setInterval('checkSession()',1000);
}
```

index.php:

```
<div class="msg" id="msg" ></div>
```

msg.php:

```
<div class="message2" id="message2" onclick="closeNotice2()" style="display: none">
Yo, <b><? echo $pusername; ?></b> - <? echo $_SESSION["user_message"]; ?> 
<a class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice2()">X</a>
</div>
```

CloseNotice2() - (just in case if you want to see that too):

```
function closeNotice2() {
    $(".message2").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

session.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_message'])) {
echo 1; 
}
```

CSS:

```
.message2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 105; /* Anything higher than 1 will do */
    background-color: #034678; 
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  height: 26 px;
  width: 100%;
}
.message2 span {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    float:left;
}
```

I think that's all. Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out the error myself, and it was the timeout() function, inside the checksession(); .. It works like a charm now :)

I just needed to remove this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.msg').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 5000);
```

I dont know how to fix this, but i will ask in another question because i find this answered now! But thanks henchman and Alan, for taking your time to try to answer me

Answer (score 1):

you are querying session.php, and if the session variable was not set, the message will appear. if the session variable has been set, the message won't appear.

presumably your session variable 'user_message' will be set somewhere after the first page call, so that the message will not be shown again. i couldn't find such code.

your javascript is finding the message div-container by className "msg"/"message2" - this behavior is not altered when changing the id of that div with randomized numbers. what do you want to achieve using these random numbers? would you want the msg-container to show more than only once?

edit:

first, try to use the following code. is the message now showing every time?

```
function checkSession(){
     var postFilen = 'msg.php';
     $.post(postFilen, function(data){
          $(".msg").html(data).find(".message2").fadeIn("slow")
          setTimeout(function(checkSession) {
          $('.msg').fadeOut('slow');
          }, 10000);
     });
}
```

Comment: Hi. AFter ive set the variable, im calling  the fuction checksession(), that way it displays the message.. i dont understand what you mean with my javascript is finding the message div container.. doesnt it find the class.. and my point doing random numbers was "just" to try my own method, so it the message will appear again..

Comment: So the message will appear again, when its getting setted next time*

Comment: What i intended to say is that the random ids wont change the behaviour of your javascript, because the javascript is handling the message container by it's class name.

Comment: Your checksession() displays the message, if answer from session.php is "1". The answer is only "1", when the variable $_SESSION['user_message'] does not exist. What was your intention for this check?

Comment: Oh okay, yeah, as i said i just tried with the id method.. what should i do then? and you're right about that its display message if answer from session.php is 1. If it isn't 1, then theres nothing and then it should do }else{ message hide.. But how is this related to my problem? Isnt that right?

Comment: Well, you statet your problem as "The message only displays 1st time, second time it doesnt appear."&nbsp;
We found out, that it is only displayed once, because after the first call, session.php is not returning a "1"

possible approach: let session.php return "1" always then, when the message should be shown. You have to change the behaviour of session.php. When shall the message be shown? Twice? Once per day? Always?

Comment: I want it to display when you call the function checkSession();

Comment: Ive just tested to echo 1; no matter what in session.php, and it still doesnt appear, only first time

Comment: you want to display it, when calling checkSession(); do you mean every time when calling checkSession();?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be a bug in the code you posted. I think the variable `$_SESSION['user_message']` changed at some point (i.e. deleted or set to null, false or zero). You *are* setting its value at some point after all, otherwise it wouldn't result in `isset()` returning true in the first place.

It's probably much easier to debug this problem by checking the actual communication between your browser and your server, i.e. using [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or just adding an `alert(data)` right in the beginning of the JS callback.

If you don't get any alerts when the message isn't shown, the problem is with your JS (i.e. the AJAX call doesn't fire, doesn't return or the code around it is never reached). If you get an alert with something other than `1`, the problem is in the server response (if you have `display_errors` enabled, it will probably be some error message if it's really broken).

I hope you are aware that your `.msg` div is automatically fading out because of the callback in your AJAX handler, whether `.message2` has faded out yet or not. Unhiding `.message2` won't bring it back as long as `.msg` is hidden (though that won't explain why the div doesn't re-appear on another page loaded by clicking a link, entering an URL or forcing a reload). This might be a problem if you're loading all the content via AJAX and don't have any "real" URLs, though.